# Will I be able to keep everything in my Season Bank?

Tags: clash-of-clans

In the winter event when you attack people some of the loot goes into the season bank which can be collected at the end of the event. The amount I will be getting is way more than my storage can hold right now. Will I lose all of the resources that I can't store or will I be able to collect them all?

Comment: According to the [fandom wiki](https://clashofclans.fandom.com/wiki/Loot_Cart): "Like all resource collectors and the Treasury, if collecting the Loot Cart will make some type of your resources overflow, the excess part will remain in the Loot Cart and won't be lost." I cant say its safe to assume thats the case with the season bank, but this might be the best info to go off of. That being said, I think if you purchase resources, it allows your collection to overflow i.e. if you have 5m/7m elixir and you buy 5m elixir, it will hold the full 10m.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end of the season all of your resources from your season bank go to your storage. You get all of the resources no matter how small your storage is.